# jquery animation control through scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to control animation through the scroll, 
that means that once the scroll reaches a certain number it just completes the animation
that means I cant pause the animation by pausing my scrolling action
This is a singular trigger in which the previous change is just animated with a delay
I want gradual change to the shape corresponding to the percentage of the page height scrolled
if the page has been scrolled 10% down. the square should be 10% more circular
and so on
but It needs to happen using a single block of code, not be setting multiple triggers
so that it's smooth and not abrupt

I have tried this but this all happens at once. I need to control it with scroll.

```
var canSee = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 60 && canSee) {
    $("#square").animate({ 
      'height': '50px',
      'width': '50px',
      'background-color':'#555',
      'border-radius': '50%'
    });
    canSee = false;
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 60 && !canSee) {
    $("#square").animate({ 
      'border-radius': '0%'
    });
    canSee = true;
  }
});
```

```
<style>
  *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .parent{
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 130vh;
    padding: 20% 50%;
  }

  #square {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #555;
  }
</style>
```

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

I expect to control this layout by scroll

Comment: You can try https://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) (IO), this was developed to solve problems like yours

Basically: You don't listen to scroll event and calculate where an element is, you just observe one (or many) elements and react ot them as they become visible, are fully visible or leaving the page.

first, you have to specify the options for the observer:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: .2
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

here we say once an element is 20% percent visible we will trigger our callback function. adjust these options to your needs obviously.

then you specify which elements you want to watch:

```
let target = document.querySelectorAll('.elements');
observer.observe(target);
```

Finally you specify what should happen in the callback function:

let callback = (entries, observer) => { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
  });
};

You can even use [official polyfill from w3c](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver) to support older browsers.

also check this example, the color of the [square changes depending on how much is visible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Result) on the page.

If you don't need IO anymore you can also [call unobserve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve) to stop observing of an element.